# returning member function display with string? C#

Tags: c#

So with this member function I'm suppose to "invoke the base class displayTime method and then add the time zone to the output message"

```
 public string DisplayTime()
        {
            //return base.displayTime();
            return "okay";
        }//end of DisplayTime
```

base class:

```
public void displayTime()
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now; // Use current time
            string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"; // Use this format
            MessageBox.Show(time.ToString(format)); // Write to console

        }//end of displayTime
```

Sadly my first DisplayTime isn't setup correctly because i'm not entirely sure how to set it up. i've tried different conbomations when it comes to "return (" " + base.displayTime());" etc etc and that didn't work. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base class method should be virtual and RETURN a string

```
public virtual string DisplayTime()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now; // Use current time
    string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"; // Use this format
    return time.ToString(format); // Write to console
}
```

then your descendant

```
        public override string DisplayTime()
        {
            return  base.displayTime() + " Some time zone";
        }//end of DisplayTime
```

Go back and re read the chapter on inheritance etc...

Comment: Thank you. I just did and really our teacher didn't give us much of a guide for this project.

Answer (score 7):

Your `displayTime()` returns void and `DisplayTime()` is supposed to return string.
So, if you want to be able to write `return base.displayTime();` you have to change `displayTime()` to return string, for example:

```
public string displayTime()
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now; // Use current time
            string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"; // Use this format
            return (time.ToString(format)); // Write to console

        }//end of displayTime
```

Comment: This misses the point that the asker is trying to implement inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Since `void displayTime()` doesn't return anything and does not take any parameters it is impossible to  change anything in it's behaviour.

Now if it was :

```
string  displayTime()
{
  ...
 // MessageBox.Show(time.ToString(format)); 
  return time.ToString(format)); 
}
```

then, in a derived class you could do:

```
public string DisplayTime()
{
    //return base.displayTime();
    return base.displayTime() + "A TimeZone";
}//end of DisplayTime
```

Note that the `base.` part is not necessary in that code (but it is allowed).

If you were to change the `d` into a `D`, the names would be the same and then you would have to use `base.` to indicate which one to use.